# Using the logical order of precedence, how can we show that the following two sentences are not equivalent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can we show that the following two sentences are not equivalent?

\begin{align}
(X \land Y) \lor Z \\
X \land (Y \lor Z)
\end{align}

I know that ∧ comes before ∨, but how can that be applied here without using truth tables?

Comment: *Equivalence* means having the same truth value. Thus, you have to find a suitable truth assignment that produces a different value for the two formulas. Try with $Z$ true and $X$ false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show the two statements
\begin{align*}
P:\;\;\;\;&(X \land Y) \lor Z\\[4pt]
Q:\;\;\;\;&X \land (Y \lor Z)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
are not equivalent.

With or without truth tables, you need to show that for *some* choice of truth values for the variables $X,Y,Z$, one statement will have a different truth value than the other.

In this case, if $X$ is false, then regardless of the truth values of $Y,Z$, statement $Q$ will be false. But statement $P$ can be made true if $Z$ is true, regardless of the truth values of $X,Y$.

So for example, you can use the choices
$$X = \text{false},\;Y = \text{anything},\;Z = \text{true}$$
to show that the statements are not equivalent.

Note that to show two statements are *not* equivalent, all you need is *one* example for which the truth values are not the same.